# Calculate name number

Tags: r

I would like to calculate name number for a set of given names.

Name number is calculated by summing the value assigned to each alphabet. The values are given below:

```
a=i=j=q=y=1
b=k=r=2
c=g=l=s=3
d=m=t=4
h=e=n=x=5
u=v=w=6
o=z=7
p=f=8
```

Example: Name number of David can be calculated as follows:

```
D+a+v+i+d
4+1+6+1+4
16=1+6=7
```

Name number of David is 7.

I would like to write a function in R for doing this. 
I am thankful for any directions or tips or package suggestions that I should look into.

Comment: Do you have a question? Stackoverflow is a question and answer site.

Comment: Edited my question. I hope this is fine now. Sorry this is my first post here.

Comment: It seems to be a recursive process to map the number into the range [1,9]

Comment: @TotalNoob You really should lay out a specification for what you're doing with that mapping though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm sure there are several ways to do this, but here's an approach using a named vector:

```
x <- c(
  "a"=1,"i"=1,"j"=1,"q"=1,"y"=1,
  "b"=2,"k"=2,"r"=2,
  "c"=3,"g"=3,"l"=3,"s"=3,
  "d"=4,"m"=4,"t"=4,
  "h"=5,"e"=5,"n"=5,"x"=5,
  "u"=6,"v"=6,"w"=6,
  "o"=7,"z"=7,
  "p"=8,"f"=8)
##
name_val <- function(Name, mapping=x){
  split <- tolower(unlist(strsplit(Name,"")))
  total <-sum(mapping[split])
  ##
  sum(as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(as.character(total),split=""))))
}
##
Names <- c("David","Betty","joe")
##
R> name_val("David")
[1] 7
R> sapply(Names,name_val)
David Betty   joe 
    7     7     4
```

Comment: Someone downvoted all of them.  Hopefully they post a great answer

Comment: @RichardScriven I think Santa left them a lump of coal yesterday and they are taking our their frustrations on SO.

Comment: I downvoted.  I don't believe it meets the specs.  You can end up with a result > 10 with this method.  I think the OP needs to provide a little bit more clarification but as I see the problem this doesn't actually provide a correct solution in all cases.  No coal for me - it's just how I vote when I think a solution isn't really correct. See @raghu's solution (in particular the last two lines) for a clever way to reduce the answer down to specification.

Comment: @nrussell Thanks a lot for the solution. Sorry if the question was not so clear. I will make a clean post next time.

Comment: @Dason, I think downvoting here was unreasonable. First, the broad guidelines for up/down-voting are "This answer is useful"/"...not useful". The OP asked for "tips". This should be more than enough to get them started. Second, there's nothing that says that we are obliged to answer in such a way that we account for all of an OP's specs. The combination of answers here should be sufficient for them to formulate their own approach that suits their specs most directly (which is likely to be of little use to future SO users, even if these answers are independently useful for similar problems).

Comment: @AnandaMahto Maybe so - but I saw a solution that met what I interpreted as the specs (raghu's) and other solutions that didn't meet the specs.  If OP provides clarifications that say this is fine then I can change my vote.  It's not like I'm saying "You're a bad person and you should feel bad" - I'm just saying that I don't think the answer is correct and since it gives what seems to be a reasonable solution in a lot of cases (but not in ALL cases at least according to my understanding) that makes it slightly dangerous.  We can disagree but that's my logic in how I voted here.

Answer (score 10):

This code snippet will accomplish what you want:

```
# Name for which the number should be computed.
name <- "David"

# Prepare letter scores array. In this case, the score for each letter will be the array position of the string it occurs in.
val <- c("aijqy", "bkr", "cgls", "dmt", "henx", "uvw", "oz", "pf")

# Convert name to lowercase.
lName <- tolower(name)             

# Compute the sum of letter scores.
s <- sum(sapply(unlist(strsplit(lName,"")), function(x) grep(x, val)))

# Compute the "number" for the sum of letter scores. This is a recursive operation, which can be shortened to taking the mod by 9, with a small correction in case the sum is 9.
n <- (s %% 9)
n <- ifelse(n==0, 9, n)
```

'n' is the result that you want for any 'name'

Answer (score 6):

You will want to create a vector of values, in alphabetical order, then use `match` to get their indices. Something like this:

```
a <- i <- j <- q <- y <- 1
b <- k <- r <- 2
c <- g <- l <- s <- 3
d <- m <- t <- 4
h <- e <- n <- x <- 5
u <- v <- w <- 6
o <- z <- 7
p <- f <- 8

vals <- c(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z)
sum(vals[match(c("d","a","v","i","d"), letters)])
```